# ASP.NET: Gridview Formatting Columns with DataFormatString

Tags: asp.net, gridview, formatting, format, boundfield

I want to change these values with [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) properties in `Gridview`.

`1.000000` --> `1` --> Deleting all digits after `.`

`366705.000000` --> `366,705` --> Deleting all digits after `.` and put the comma for seperate.

`12.830000` --> `%12,83` --> Delete last 4 digits after `.` and put `%` (% is optinal not must)

BTW, Is there any link to suggest me otherwise [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx). I analyze very well this page but sometimes still can't find what I need about data format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.  I didn't test #3 - if it's not right, it's close.

## 1

Convert the `number` to an `int`.

## 2

```
String.Format("{0:n"}, 366705);
```

## 3

```
(12.83 / 100).ToString("{%#0.00}", el-GR);
```

A couple helpful formatting web pages:

- [Custom Numeric Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)
- [SteveX Compiled - blog with many samples](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)